# Can't open GUI wallet with Ledger Nano S after 1.5.5 firmware update

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, ledger

Recently I updated my Ledger Nano S with the 1.5.5 version of firmware. After typing in the GUI password, I am asked to press tick (confirm) button on my Nano S -  "Export Key" - in order to open the wallet. Unfortunately, when I press the tick (confirm) button, the Nano S does not respond and I cannot get into the GUI wallet. The Nano S display just shows "Export Key", which appears to be frozen and does not respond to either the tick (confirm) button or the cross (reject) button.

I run macOS and the latest 10.13.04 Monero GUI.

Anyone experiencing the same problem?

Comment: This is a known issue unfortunately. See: https://github.com/LedgerHQ/ledger-app-monero/issues/29

Comment: Thanks dEBRYNE, no doubt I can always count on your support. Well, I'll get hold of a non-1.5.5 Ledger nano S tomorrow (think it's 1.4.2) and try if it works again. And if so, perhaps use it for funds transfer until this issue is resolved for the 1.5.5 updated devices.

Comment: I *think* a device with 1.4.2 should still function properly. If not, let me know.

Comment: Ok, just got in the GUI without any problems whatsoever but with 1.4.2. Still no joy with 1.5.5.

Comment: Just to confirm, is this the right GUI version I have? :    GUI version: v013.0.3-14-g1c6f1e1 (Qt 5.7.0); Embedded Monero version: v0.13.0.4.

Comment: That's the latest and correct GUI version, yes. Thus, to be clear, the GUI works properly with 1.4.2, but does not work with 1.5.5 right?

Comment: Also, have you seen this? https://github.com/LedgerHQ/ledger-app-monero/issues/29#issuecomment-456225083

Comment: Yes, that is correct. 1.4.2 works perfectly, but 1.5.5 doesn't. And yes, am following that thread, thanks.

Comment: I've been monitoring here, GitHub, and Reddit, but so far have noticed nothing. Has anybody heard anything about a fix for the breakage of Monero GUI/CLI and Ledger firmware 1.5.5 and Monero app 1.1.2?

Comment: I don't believe there is a solution yet. Ledger CTO mentioned of Reddit posted a week or so ago "This is being addressed" but nothing came out of it yet. Disappointing. Moved to Cake Wallet until this is sorted. Here: https://www.reddit.com/r/ledgerwallet/comments/aicmq4/monero_not_working_with_latest_firmware_and_app/

Comment: Has there been any ground made with this?

Comment: @anon445454 - Not yet as far as I know. You can follow the progress here -> https://github.com/LedgerHQ/ledger-app-monero/issues/29#issuecomment-456225083